# Coordinate system with tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to use `tikz-3dplot` to draw a cube and I was particularly interested by the possibility to define a point using `\tdplotsetcoord` which allows to get x/y/z/xz... coordinates. But when I try to define a point in (4,4,4) of the main coordinate system of `tikz-3dplot` (so `\tdplotsetcoord{P}{sqrt(3)*4}{45}{45}` I think), I do not get what I am expecting as you can see below. The blue and black nodes should be the same in my figure. Any ideas ?

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

% cube
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{sqrt(3)*4}{45}{45}
\draw[dashed] 
  (0,0,0) -- (Px)
  (0,0,0) -- (Py)
  (0,0,0) -- (Pz);
\draw[->] 
  (Px) -- ++ (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[->]
   (Py) -- ++(0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[->] 
  (Pz) -- ++(0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\draw[thick]
  (Pxz) -- (P) -- (Pxy) -- (Px) -- (Pxz) -- (Pz) -- (Pyz) -- (P); 
\draw[thick]
  (Pyz) -- (Py) -- (Pxy);

\filldraw[dashed,blue] (0,0,0)-- (P) circle (2pt);

\filldraw[dashed] (0,0,0)-- (4,4,4) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Could you please explain why you expect that`(r*cos(theta)*cos(phi),r*cos(theta)*sin(phi),r*sin(theta))=(4,4,4)` for `theta=phi=45`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! One way to compute the spherical coordinates of `(4,4,4)` is to solve

```
(r*cos(theta)*cos(phi),r*cos(theta)*sin(phi),r*sin(theta))=(4,4,4)
```

which gives `r=4*sqrt(3)` and `phi=45`, as you got, and `theta=asin(sqrt(2/3))`, which differs from what you have. BTW, you can use also the spherical coordinates of the `3d` library, which follow slightly different conventions. The following MWE shows that the outcome is consistent with the above considerations.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mytheta}{asin(sqrt(2/3))}
\typeout{\mytheta}
% cube
\tdplotsetcoord{P}{sqrt(3)*4}{\mytheta}{45}
\draw[dashed] 
  (0,0,0) -- (Px)
  (0,0,0) -- (Py)
  (0,0,0) -- (Pz);
\draw[->] 
  (Px) -- ++ (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[->]
   (Py) -- ++(0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[->] 
  (Pz) -- ++(0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\draw[thick]
  (Pxz) -- (P) -- (Pxy) -- (Px) -- (Pxz) -- (Pz) -- (Pyz) -- (P); 
\draw[thick]
  (Pyz) -- (Py) -- (Pxy);

\filldraw[dashed,blue] (0,0,0)-- (P) circle (2pt);

\draw[green!70!black] (4,4,4) circle (3pt);

\draw[red] (xyz spherical cs:radius={4*sqrt(3)},
  longitude=45,latitude=90-\mytheta) circle (4pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]